# String index out of range: IndexError

Tags: python

Don't understand why am I getting index out of range...
tried finding the mistake with: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display

It "updates" the *i* and *l*, but I get the error even without finishing the word.

What I'm trying is to print every name that has an space no farther than its 5th character, so my expected output would be:

```
Rama as
Nemo as
```

Code:

```
spaceNames = ['Rama as', 'Nemo as', 'Siegss as', 'Kama', 'Gray', 'BB', 'BB']

for name in spaceNames:
    i=0
    for l in name:
        
        if i <= 4 and l[i] == " ":
          print(name)
        print(i)
        i+=1
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: lists and other similar structures are _iterable_ in Python, so you can directly create a for loop across them `for name in space_names:`

Comment: In your own words: where you have `if i <= 4 and l[i] == " "`, how did you decide to use the number `4`, and not any other number? In your own words, when you do `for l in name:`, what do you expect `name` to look like? What do you expect `l` to look like? How long do you think `l` will be? Now, what happened when you tried to verify those expectations (for example, using `print(l)` at the start of the loop)?

Answer (score 1):

A trivial trace of your program, or even an eyeball check, reveals that `l` is a single character.  You're using indices up to 3.  A single character has only `l[0]` as a legal reference.

We have no way to "fix" your program, as we have little idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to solve with both comments you guys did:

```
spaceNames = ['Rama as', 'Nemo as', 'Siegss as', 'Kama', 'Gray', 'BB', 'BB']

for name in spaceNames:
    i=0
    for l in name:
        if name.index(l) <=4 and name[i] == " ":
            print(name)
        i+=1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of looping when you can just get most of the conditions you were looking for more efficiently.

```
spaceNames = ['Rama as', 'Nemo as', 'Siegss as', 'Kama', 'Gray', 'BB', 'BB']

for name in spaceNames:
    idx = name.find(' ')  # This returns -1 if no space
    if idx < 0 or idx > 4:
        continue  # Skip
    print(name)
```